# nodejs passport always going to failure URL

Tags: node.js, facebook, coffeescript, passport.js

I am using passport to allow logging in through Facebook on my website. Everything seems to work just fine, but callback from Facebook's site always goes to the failureRedirect even though I get all the data back from Facebook with valid tokens. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
express = require "express"
passport = require 'passport'
FBStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy
Properties = require "./config.json"

FB_APP_ID = REMOVED
FB_APP_SECRET = REMOVED

passport.serializeUser = (user, done) ->
 done null, user

passport.deserializeUser = (obj, done) ->
  done null, obj

fb = new FBStrategy  
  clientID: FB_APP_ID
  clientSecret: FB_APP_SECRET
  callbackURL: "http://localhost/auth/facebook/callback"
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) ->
    console.log "accesToken ", accessToken
    console.log "refreshToken", refreshToken
    console.log "profile", profile
    done()

passport.use fb

app = module.exports = express.createServer()
app.Properties = Properties

console.log "starting server"
app.configure ->
  app.set "views", "./views"
  app.set "view engine", "jade"
  app.set "view options", layout: false
  app.use express.methodOverride()
  app.use (express.static "#{__dirname}")
  app.use express.cookieParser()
  app.use express.bodyParser()
  app.use (express.session secret: REMOVED, key: REMOVED)
  app.use passport.initialize()
  app.use passport.session()
  app.use app.router

app.configure "development", ->
  app.listen Properties.Port


app.get "/", (request, response) -> 
  { session: Session } = request
  response.render "index"

app.get "/account", (request, response) -> 
  { session: Session } = request
  response.render "account"

app.get "/login", (request, response) -> 
  { session: Session } = request
  response.render "login", {user:request.user}

app.get "/auth/facebook", passport.authenticate 'facebook'

app.get "/auth/facebook/callback", passport.authenticate ('facebook', {failureRedirect: "/login"}), (req, res) ->
  res.redirect "/account"


console.log "server is ready and listening on port #{Properties.Port}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply a user in the strategy's verify callback.  Something like this:

```
fb = new FBStrategy  
  clientID: FB_APP_ID
  clientSecret: FB_APP_SECRET
  callbackURL: "http://localhost/auth/facebook/callback"
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) ->
    console.log "accesToken ", accessToken
    console.log "refreshToken", refreshToken
    console.log "profile", profile
    user = {} // find or create a user in your database
    done(null, user)
```

You can read more about verify callbacks in the guide: http://passportjs.org/guide/configuration.html

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. I was thinking I needed to do the user stuff after calling done().

Comment: passing `done(null, 0)` worked for me. But passing '{}' gave this error: "500 Error: failed to serialize user into session"

Comment: I'd check you're `serializeUser` function.  It's probably throwing an exception.